# Automatically assign tags based on a single parent value

Tags: content-editor, taxonomy

I'm new to Sitecore and am hoping someone can help. What is the best/easiest way to set this up for content editors so that if they choose a value from one tree, it automatically tags for other assigned values.

For example if I choose value X, it automatically also selects A and C from tree 2, and A,B and F from tree 4. If I choose value Y, it automatically also selects B and G from tree 2 and A and C from tree 5.

Is this something I can do with tag groups?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please clarify if you are talking about the tree-list field?

Comment: Thanks, Andrey. If that's the best way to do it, we can use a tree-list field. This is for a new implementation, so I'm trying to figure out how best to architect the taxonomy to meet the business need. Any option is open at this point.

Comment: @Dan, you need to make a little bit more effort to explain what you're trying to achieve. Add some examples, screenshots, whatever you think might be useful.

Comment: OK, sorry. Let's try this. Say I have a Sitecore set up with a content taxonomy that includes three taxonomy trees - "Fruit Name," "Color" and "Source."  If a content editor chooses "Apple" as the fruit name, SiteCore also automatically tags "Red" from the color taxonomy tree and "Washington" from the "Source" taxonomy tree. Other tags can also be chosen, but content tagged for "Apple" is also always automatically tagged for "Red" and "Washington."

Comment: My question is whether there is a way to set up a mechanism like that other than with custom coding.

Comment: As far as I know this will be custom